# Вычисление интервала

Tags: javascript, дата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача следующая.На данной линейке расположены даты,от текущей и на месяц вперед.
Каждая ячейка имеет вот такую структуру `<div class="td day" data-date="06/04/2016">`
Далее при клике на любую ячейку открывается попап с выбором начала даты и конца,вот этот интервал я должен закрасить на линейке другим цветом.Пока что получается закрасить только начальную и конечную дату,с интервалом пока не могу разобраться как лучше сделать,пробовал через цикл и `next()` идти по соседям и получать значения `data-date` пока не дойду до конечной даты,но не получилось.

```
var stuffUserId;
    var stuffDay;
    var stuffRow;

    //TRACK PANEL POPUP
    $('.display-table').on('click', '.day', function(){
        stuffDay = $(this);
        stuffRow = stuffDay.parent('.tr');
        var trackModal = $('.track-modal');
        stuffUserId = stuffDay.parent('.tr').attr('data-user-id');
        trackModal.find('input[name=start_date]').val(stuffDay.attr('data-date'));
    });

    $('#modal-1').on('click', '#book-time', function(){
        var bookTimeForm = $('#book-time-form').serialize(); 
        var btn = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url : '/stuff/book_time',
            method : 'POST',
            data : bookTimeForm + '&user_id=' + stuffUserId,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                if(data.message == 'success'){

                    //START-END DATE
                    stuffDay.find('a').addClass(data.reason_color + ' ' + data.start_part);
                    //stuffDay.find('a').next('.td a').addClass(data.reason_color);
                    stuffRow.find('.td[data-date="' + data.end_date + '"] a').addClass(data.reason_color + ' ' + data.end_part);

                }else{
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        if(value != ''){
                            btn.parents('.modal-content').find('.' + key).addClass('validation-error');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Вот получилось таким способом,на сколько он корректен правда в данной ситуации не знаю,но работает.

```
 var notedDay = stuffDay.attr('data-date');
                    var nextDay = stuffDay;

                    while(notedDay != data.end_date){
                        nextDay = nextDay.next('.td');
                        nextDay.find('a').addClass(data.reason_color);
                        notedDay = nextDay.next('.td').attr('data-date');
                    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте пройтись циклом по .eq(i) , где i - номер элемента в селекторе.

Comment: А что конкретно не получилось? Можно же перебрать все даты (а лучше и идти по порядку, если они уже упорядочены) и закрасить те, которые в заданном интервале. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Так вот и интересует сам момент как лучше двигаться по данному интервалу,в цикле через next() шел по соседям и считывал у каждого аттрибут data-date пока он не будет равен конченой дате,но почему то получалось какое то зацикливание.

Comment: Нашел ошибку,у меня каждый раз next() ищет от ячейки по которой был клик